# How to use radio button with laravel

Tags: laravel, radio-button, migration

I am trying to learn laravel 5, so I strated by creating some simple forms.
My form contains (id, title,..) and radio button

```
<label for="importance">Importance</label>
<input type="radio" name="Importance"
<?php if (isset($importance) && $importance=="tres_important") echo "checked";?>
    value="tres_important">très important
<input type="radio" name="importance"
    <?php if (isset($importance) && $importance=="important") echo "checked";?>
    value="important">important
```

Now, I need to know what I should add to my migration file, to make it work "create_projets_table"

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id',true);
        $table->string('title');
        $table->date('dateDebut');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Thank you in advance

UPDATES :

Based on the comments bellow, I made some changes, but still not working, it seems like something went wrong with "submit.blade.php"

submit.blade.php :

```
 <div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="tres_important" name="importance" value="tres_important">Très important</label>

    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="important" name="importance" value="important">Important</label>
 </div>
```

and this is my migration "create_projets_table.php" :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id',true);
        $table->string('title');
        $table->date('dateDebut');
        $table->date('dateFin');
        $table->float('cout');      
        $table->integer('importance');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
 }
```

This route.php :

```
Route::post('/submit', function(Request $request) {
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|max:255',
    'annee_realisation' => 'required|max:255',
    'cout' => 'required|max:255',
    'importance' => 'required',
]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validator);
}

    $projet = new \App\Projet;
    $projet->title = $request->title;
    $projet->annee_realisation = $request->annee_realisation;
    $projet->cout = $request->cout;
    $projet->importance = $request->importance;

    $projet->save();

    return redirect('/');
});
```

And this my controller "Project_Controller" :

```
class Project_Controller extends Controller
{
//
$this->validate(request(), [
'importance' => 'required'
]);
}
```

I got the following error :

Undefined variable : importance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2FbS.png)

Comment: it is `echo Form::radio('name', 'value', true);` in laravel's blade template

Comment: And what about the migration, we don't change anything ?

Comment: You'll probably need to have a corresponding column in your table. E.g. `$table->boolean('important')`.

Comment: @RikardOlsson should I add 1 or 2 columns each choice correspond to a column ?

Comment: Either so, but more efficient would probably be to do `$table->integer('importance')` and use maybe a zero to indicate "important" and one to indicate "more important" and so on

Comment: @RikardOlsson  
Please check the post I edited it

Comment: I think you need to have a look at using migrations. There should be no logic when creating your table(s). To correct your updated answer: just use `$table->integer('importance');` and not `$table->integer('tres_important')`. When inserting a row you will determine by your given integer the level of importance :)

Comment: Can you please upload the code for the Projet -model? You can also remove your code inside the controller. You're currently executing all logic in the routes-file, which for now i think is ok, but you probably should consider moving it to a function in your controller

Comment: You are right, I've changed the code, and it's finally working. I created a method store() in project_controller instead of executing all logic in route-file

Answer (score 3):

You can use laravel form methods, like below

```
Form::radio('name', 'value', true);
```

Example:

```
<label class="radio inline">
    {!! Form ::radio('importance','tres_important',($importance == 'tres_important' ? true : false)) !!}
    Très important
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
    {!! Form ::radio('importance','important',($importance == 'important' ? true : false)) !!}
    Important
</label>
```

Read Documentation https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere in your code you have set the value of "$importance", can you show the code where you set that value?.

Your checking to see if its set which is fine, but then also checking its value.

```
if (isset($importance) && $importance=="tres_important"
```

if it is not set you cant chcek it to see what the value is, which is what it looks like your trying to do in the code i can see. Thats where your undefined error is coming from. If you can post full code it will be easier to track down